# How does wordpress calculate the page depth?

Tags: pages, wp-list-pages

When using functions such as `wp_list_pages()`, WordPress gives you the `depth` option. How is it calculated?

Is it stored somewhere in the DB? (I couldn't find it).

Or is it calculated in a loop checking post parents?

What's strange is that `wp_list_pages()` offer the parameter `depth` but that function is based of `get_pages()` which doesn't have that same option available.

Comment: `wp_list_pages()` only uses `get_pages()` to (sic!) get pages, `walk_page_tree()` does the hierarchical structuring.

Comment: @ialocin ... and don't forget to add this as an answer ;-)

Comment: But it isn't actually an answer to the question. @birgire May be I should just extend it though..

Comment: I will take a look at walk_page_tree(), but feel free to extend it a little and post as the answer.

Comment: I'm sure you will add good spice to it @ialocin ;-) I guess one could say that on the other side of this, is the `wp_post.post_parent` field in the DB.

Comment: The post_parent field doesn't give you the depth, just the fact that it has a parent. Which means I need to loop through it until post_parent = 0. I was just wondering how WP was calculating the depth argument. Thank you!

Comment: yes that's of course true, but the tree structure is stored in the post_parent field and then the page walker will chew on that to calculate the depth. @gdaniel

Comment: Agreed, but it would be great to have a breakdown of the walk_page_tree function.

Comment: Tried my best as always, thanks for encouraging me, I did not plan on posting an answer. @birgire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, lets break it down, all the links are going to be to the source code.

[`wp_list_pages()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L1079) only [uses `get_pages()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L1111) to (sic!) get pages, [`walk_page_tree()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L1254) does the hierarchical structuring [inside it](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L1127). The further course of the process goes [`Walker_Page`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L1292) - and the generic [`Walker`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php#L14) of course -, unless a custom walker is used. Inside `walk_page_tree()` [you will see](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L1283), the walkers [`walk`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php#L191) method is called, which subsequently calls the [`display_element`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php#L132) method. Mainly in the `display_element`, but also in the `walk`, method you find the handling of the depth.

To make it short: the depth is handled by iterating, `display_element` [calls itself](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php#L160) until the end or the given `depth` parameter.

Comment: My pleasure, I learned something myself too :) I linked it up for you (and others) - surely helpful for getting quicker into it. @gdaniel